# Certain Trace logs aren't being associated with a Request

Tags: azure, logging, azure-application-insights

[image]

This is the trace from our .NET API (ASP.NET & NancyFX) hosted on Azure. All of the trace statements belong to the request displayed at the bottom. The calls to the trace function aren't actually in the base request method, but within async functions called from the base request method. As you can see in the image, some of the trace messages have been assigned an 'Operation Id' (Request id) but some haven't. If I click on that request I can drill down and see those 3 initial traces, but not the latter 2. What I've had to do is insert a unique ID myself into the trace message, [39203984] in this instance, so I can tie them all together when filtering. I can't see any reason why some are linked and others not. From the image it appears the non Verbose traces are the problem, but that isn't always the case. It does make reading the logs that much more difficult.

Traces are all generated with the 'new' TrackTrace() function of Insights.

Answer (score 0):

this will *generally* occur if the trace things occur while there's an asp.net request context available when the async code runs.  this is set up by the operation correlation initializer here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/8c51d66c08c1baf0844613637fa5d3ccfc7590f9/Src/Web/Web.Shared.Net/OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer.cs

which tries to use the requests's operation context id when it can, and here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/75373e57dcf8d646c54ee188461c373f2cc98939/Src/Web/Web.Shared.Net/OperationNameTelemetryInitializer.cs

to create an operation name.

you can manually set operation.id and operation.name properties in the context if you know better than the initializer can guess.  it looks like you're doing that, but just sending it as part of the trace instead of setting the operation.id field yourself?

Comment: It's a little more rudimentary than that. I'm simply creating a unique value (Hash code of the request) in the request, and passing it along the method calls to be inserted in the trace's title.

Comment: i understand.  i'm saying if you take that hash you are generating, and just set it as the context.operationid field in the telemetry you generate (on the request, etc, replacing the "Default" one), all of the other things in AI would "just work".  all items for this operation, things like that.  That's the intended use for the operation id field, to correlate the various types of telemetry together.   that way you can join on that field in queries and stuff, instead of trying to parse it out of strings.